# How to read seperate fields in a csv file and compare with user input?

Tags: ios, xcode, csv

I am building an app where use can upload a csv file that contains First Name, Last Name and email in 3 seperate columns. User interface will have 3 text fields and a button. When user enters the first name or last name or email, and click search button, the whole documenent must be searched and display an alert saying that the record was found in the file. This is the function that I am using, but it only reads the first row and first column. Please help

```
- (void) SearchStudent

{

    NSArray *DocumentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);



    NSString *DocumentDirectory = [DocumentPath objectAtIndex:0];



    NSString *FullPath = [DocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"example.csv"]];



    NSString * pstrCSVFile= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:FullPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];



    NSArray * paRowsOfCSVFile= [pstrCSVFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSArray *paColumnsOfRow;

    NSString *pstrFirstColumn;



    for(NSString * pstrRow in paRowsOfCSVFile)

    {

        paColumnsOfRow= [pstrRow componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        pstrFirstColumn= [paColumnsOfRow objectAtIndex:0];

        if([pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:GWIDText.text] == NSOrderedSame)

        {

            UIAlertView *alertingFileName = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alertingFileName show];

            break;

        }

        else

        {

            UIAlertView *alertingFileName1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Not Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alertingFileName1 show];

            break;

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your **else** statement is breaking out of the **for** loop if the first name doesn't match. You'll want to remove that and perhaps add a variable to track if you've found a match. Only set it if you match the name. After your **for** loop, check the variable to see if there was a match. If not, then show your UIAlertView for "Not Found".

Comment: Oh ya... I actually tried without else block itself... But it still just checks the first row first column

Comment: What is \[paRowsOfCSVFile count\] equal to? If it's only 1 and your file has multiple lines, do you need to split on "\r" instead of "\n"?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of hints:

1. You are checking for one column only.

   ```
   if([pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:GWIDText.text] == NSOrderedSame)
   ```

Do the same with the other two columns. Then you will solve your first problem of only checking one column.

1. Looks like the line terminator is not correct. Depending on which platform the csv file was created, it might have different line terminator. I would suggest taking a text editor like notepad++ for instance and viewing hidden code to find out your line terminator. Then use the terminator to split rows. Make sure you are getting more than 1 row (just output the rows variable].

Comment: How to check multiple lines? I tried \n and \r for termination... I use normal nodepad to create csv file