# How to compare and verify user input with a csv file columns data?

Tags: ios, xcode, csv

I am trying to get answer for the last few weeks. I want to give a textfield to users in the app and ask them to enter a id number and this number will be checked with the uploaded csv file columns. If it matches then display an alert saying that its found a match or else it doesn't.

Comment: So what have you tried. Which bit are you stuck with etc.

Answer (score 0):

A csv file is basically a normal file in which items are separated by commas. 
For example:

```
id,name,email
1,Joe,joe@d.com
2,Pat,pat@d.com
```

To get the list of IDs stored in this csv files, simply loop through the lines, and grab the first item after splitting the string (use comma to split)

```
id = line.split(",").get(0); // first element ** Note this depends on what language you're using
```

Now, add this id to a collection of ids you are storing, like in a list.

```
 IDs.add(id);
```

When you take the user input, all you need to do is to check if the id is in your list of ids.

```
 if (IDs.contains(userId)) { print "Found"; }
```

Comment: I don't want to store it in a list. But I want to directly check with the file. Here is the question, I previously asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589545/how-to-read-seperate-fields-in-a-csv-file-and-compare-with-user-input ... Can you look into it and help me please?